# SuSE: how to get /etc/resolv.conf updated with IPv6 name server?

Tags: domain-name-system, linux-networking, ipv6, sles

I have a SuSE 11 Linux VM, it has both ipv4 and ipv6 enabled, the network this VM connecting to supports both v4 and v6.

After the VM boot up, it holds both IPv4 and v6 addresses, but `/etc/resolv.conf` contains only IPv4 name server.

Now I want a pure IPv6 VM, so I disabled IPv4 interface with command:

```
# ifconfig eth0 0
```

After that, `eth0` holds only IPv6 addresses:

```
# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:00:2B:AC:EF:2D
          inet6 addr: fd01:1:2:2912:0:2bff:feac:ef2d/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::2bff:feac:ef2d/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:650410 errors:0 dropped:50427 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:615 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:42128916 (40.1 Mb)  TX bytes:148434 (144.9 Kb)
```

But `/etc/resolv.conf` is not updated, it still contains only IPv4 name server. Then I tried to edit `/etc/sysconfig/networkifcfg-eth0`:

```
DEVICE=eth0
BOOTPROTO='dhcp6'
STARTMODE='auto'
TYPE=Ethernet
USERCONTROL='no'
DHCLIENT6_MODE=managed
```

And restarted network service:

```
# service network restart
```

After that, `/etc/resolv.conf` became to empty. So my question is, how can I get `/etc/resolv.conf` to updated by DHCPv6?

Comment: SuSE 11 is _very_ old. Can you use something that was released in the last few years?

Comment: Michael Hampton, but that's the whole point of the enterprise Linux distro -- super long term support. SLES11 is still supported :-)